# How to Inject a Build Environment Variable Computed from a Jenkins Run Parameter?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I understand how to use the EnvInject plugin to compute variables from string parameters (the parameter name simply is an unbound variable in the groovy script performing the injection).

I want to use a Run Parameter - the parameter that contains the latest successful build of a project (or whichever build the user selects), but it appears that any of those are not available at the time the EnvInject plugin runs.

I guess I need to write groovy code to inspect the desired project myself and get the right build name directly from the model - except I can't do that, since the model lives on the master and the envInject plugin runs on the slave....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EnvInject can run at different times...

- At node/master level (on startup, and available always).
- At job startup, before SCM step (configured at the top of job configuration).
- After SCM step (configured under "build environment" section).
- As a build step.

You should either last or second-last options, if you want build parameters to be available

Lastly, there is another option to try. Get [**pre-scm-buildstep**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/pre-scm-buildstep) plugin. This allows to run any build step (including EnvInject), just before the SCM checkout. I've done a quick test, and the job parameters and their values *are* available at this stage.

Comment: I sadly only know which branch to check out after I get the run parameters, so running it after the SCM step will defeat the purpose, unless I punt and run the SCM checkout from within the build task.

Now, if the run parameter would let me get at the git hash used....

Comment: Edited the answer with **pre-scm-buildstep** plugin option. This worked for me.

Comment: ... and yet another plugin ... Jenkins is sooo much fun!